# How to resolve these errors and install ClamAV for Perl under Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, perl, clamav, cpan

After successful

```
apt-get install clamav
```

I then did:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
install File::Scan::ClamAV
```

and got

```
  CPAN.pm: Going to build J/JA/JAMTUR/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91.tar.gz

Cannot find clamd in /root/bin (or a number of other places)
 - are you sure clamav in installed?
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
  JAMTUR/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Failed during this command:
 JAMTUR/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91.tar.gz          : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site' returned status 512
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clamd means clamav daemon. You need install clamav-daemon package.

Comment: I no longer have this problem so I can't verify your solution. But I'm going to select your answer because it's the only one with an up vote.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the command `dh-make-perl` very helpful, as it allows CPAN modules to be easily converted into .debs

On my system, with the package "clamav-daemon" (not just "clamav") installed, the command 
`dh-make-perl --cpan File::Scan::ClamAV --build` successfully builds a .deb, which then installs fine with `dpkg -i`

Also possibly of interest, a different clamav interface, libclamav-client-perl, already exists in the Debian repos, and also in Ubuntu universe

Comment: The `dh-make-perl` command failed for me but I was able to cd into the build directory it created and simply type `make install` and it installed a working .pm file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to install ClamAV on debian you can refer to this article -

[ClamAV installation on Debian](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/clamav.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This is the official documentation for debian volatile:

http://www.debian.org/volatile/

By the way, ther error from the cpan shell is that it searches clamd in your root homedir. It cannot find it and boms out